# Callback after Redux Thunk function: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, redux-thunk

**Problem**

I have an async function in redux (with redux thunk) that set a value in the redux store.  It is used many times throughout my app but, I want different things to happen after the redux function runs using the new values that the redux function sets.  Seems like a good reason for a callback, right?  So I tried doing just this, but I got the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

**Logic in Attempt to fix**

I *thought* the reason might be that although the redux function dispatches actions, it doesn't actually return anything.  Therefore, I added `returns` in the redux function thinking that the function would return something back to the component that called it, which would resolve the error I am receiving.  No Luck.

---

**Question:**

**Does anyone know how I can perform functions *after* an async redux function (with redux thunk) runs and finishes setting a new value in the redux store?**

---

**My Most Recent Attempt to Solve**

**Component**

```
import {fetchUser} from './../actions/index.js';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Attempt #1: this.props.fetchUserData()); // originally I attempted just running one function and then the rest without a callback but the new value was not set in redux store before the next function that needed it ran
    // Attempt #2: this.props.fetchUserData().then(function() => {  // I also tried running just a standard .then(function()
    // Attempt #3: (line below) 
    this.props.fetchUserData().then((resultFromReduxFunction) => {
      console.log("fetchUserData result = " + resultFromReduxFunction);

      // do some stuff with the new data
      console.log("this.props.reduxData.userHairColor = " + this.props.reduxData.userHairColor);
      console.log("this.props.reduxData.userHeight = " + this.props.reduxData.userHeight);
    });
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        reduxData: state.user
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
      fetchUserData: fetchUserData
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

**Action Creator**

```
export const set = (idToSet, payloadToSet) => {
  return {
    type: 'SET',
    id: idToSet,
    payload: payloadToSet
  }
}

export const fetchUserData = (callbackFunction) => {
  console.log("fetchUserData triggered...");
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("no user logged in");
        return false // Added in attempt to fix callback 
      } else {
        // fetch some more user data
        firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(user.uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
          var userHairColor = snapshot.child(userHairColor).val();
          var userHeight = snapshot.child(userHeight).val();
          dispatch(set('userHairColor', userHairColor));
          dispatch(set('userHeight', userHeight));
          return true // Added in attempt to fix callback 
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**Redux Store**

```
const initialState = {
    userHairColor: "",
    userHeight: ""
}

export default function (state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.id]: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return {
        ...state
      }
  }
}
```

**Thanks in advance for any help**

Comment: `dispatch(set('userHairColor', userHairColor));` Is `set` an action creator?
Show it, if it is.

Comment: it's a reducer, I want to see action creator.

Comment: added `SET` action creator

Comment: All looks correct, your first variant should work...

Comment: in the first variant, `userHeight` and `userHairColor` were not yet to anything by the time my functions after the redux function ran (I'm guessing because the redux function is called but the async function takes some time before setting those values, meanwhile the rest of the stuff in my `componentDidMount` has now already run)

Answer (score 1):

The callback would work if you actually explicitly called it inside the thunk, but it really feels like an anti-pattern.

Instead you can dispatch another thunk that can deal with any further logic.

```
export const fetchUserData = (callbackFunction) => {
  console.log("fetchUserData triggered...");
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      ...do stuf...
      dispatch(doMoreStuff())
    })
  }
}
```

Or, if you need to react to the result inside your react component dispatch an action that will modify your redux state. That will in turn call the react life cycle methods and `render` and you can react to the change there based on the new state.

To improve the answer it would help to know what you want to do after the action is done.

Answer (score 1):

To use `.then(...)`, your thunk has to return a Promise. Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` seems to returns an unsubscribe function, not a Promise, so even if you returned that it wouldn't allow you to chain additional callbacks at your action creator call site. And you can't return from within the callback you pass to `onAuthStateChanged`, because you're in a different call stack at that point (it's asynchronous).

What you're going to have to do is pass a callback function to your action creator, which it needs to call from within the success callback of your data fetching.

Something like this:

```
export const fetchUserData = (callbackFunction) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("no user logged in");
        // You can pass false to your callback here, so that it knows the auth was unsuccessful
        callbackFunction(false); 
      } else {
        // fetch some more user data
        firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(user.uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
          var userHairColor = snapshot.child(userHairColor).val();
          var userHeight = snapshot.child(userHeight).val();
          dispatch(set('userHairColor', userHairColor));
          dispatch(set('userHeight', userHeight));
          // Passing true so your callback knows it was a success
          callbackFunction(true); 
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Then to use it as desired:

```
this.props.fetchUserData((success) => {
  console.log("fetchUserData result = " + success);

  // do some stuff with the new data
  console.log("this.props.reduxData.userHairColor = " + this.props.reduxData.userHairColor);
  console.log("this.props.reduxData.userHeight = " + this.props.reduxData.userHeight);
});
```

There's a bit of callback hell going on here, but to avoid that you'd have to use a "promisified" version of Firebase's API, in which case you could also return the promise from your thunk so that anything using your action creator could attach a `.then(...)`.

Comment: thanks for the help @philraj.  I tried this solution but it returns the following error: `callbackFunction is not a function`  .. any idea why?

Comment: @Rbar I'd have to see how you're calling `fetchUserData`, but it sounds like what you're passing to it isn't a function.

Comment: @Rbar By the way, even though I showed how to do this, I agree with Martin Kadlec's answer that this feels like an anti-pattern. See his answer for more info.

Comment: @philaj thanks for the help, and I agree that this does feel a bit like an anti-pattern.  Though, the alternative seems to be duplicating this function a number of times in components which doesn't feel like a great option either